# Getting error @types/tapable/index"' is not a constructor function type

Tags: angular, npm

My production website was working perfectly. but after putting "npm install" command on server then trying to build using "npm run build:prod" command. facing below error.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@types/tapable/index.d.ts:290:30 
    TS2314: Generic type 'HookMapInterceptor<T1, any, T2, T3>' requires 4 type argument(s).

ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@types/tapable/index.d.ts:293:38 
    TS2368: Type parameter name cannot be 'any'

ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@types/tapable/index.d.ts:293:48 
    TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'any'.
```

I tried this command "npm install @types/tapable@1.0.2". but did not resolve the issue. please help me out.

Comment: any update here?

Answer (score 3):

This could be related to this problem:

https://github.com/webpack/tapable/issues/53

Try `npm install @types/tapable@0.2.5`